# JS file not loading in the partial view - RoR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a table with toggle buttons on it on a Ruby on Rails Application.   I use bootstrap for both the tables and the toggle.

The bootstrap toggle works in the main page, while it doesn't in the partial view. Somehow the JS is not loading in the partial view, though the layouts appear fine.
When I do a simple alert using document.ready jQuery in the partial , it works though.

But not sure how to get the bootstrap toggle working in this page.

I have tried to remove the JS file link from the partial html file, but then it just displays normal checkbox elements.
I have also tried setting the turbolinks to false in the button which triggers the partial. But it is still not loading JS file.

**Main  Page View**

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

     <table
        id="usersaccess_table"
        data-pagination="true"
        class="table ">

       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="user_id">User</th>
            <th data-field="col_1" >Column 1</th>
            <th data-field="col_2">Column 2</th>
            <th data-field="col_3" >Column 3</th>
            <th data-field="col_4" >Column 4</th>       
          </tr>
      </thead>

<% @users.each do |u| %>
<tr><td><%= u[:username]%> </td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" <%=u[:col_1]==1? "checked":""%> data-toggle="toggle"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" <%=u[:col_2]==1? "checked":""%> data-toggle="toggle"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" <%=u[:col_3]==1? "checked":""%> data-toggle="toggle"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" <%=u[:col_4]==1? "checked":""%> data-toggle="toggle"></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

**Partial Page  View**

Partial which displays when a specific username input is given using another html element from Main View Page.

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

      <table
        id="user_table"
        data-pagination="true"
        class="table">

       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="col_1" >Column 1</th>
            <th data-field="col_2">Column 2</th>
            <th data-field="col_3" >Column 3</th>
            <th data-field="col_4" >Column 4</th>       
          </tr>
      </thead>

<% @users.each do |u| %>
  <td><input type="checkbox" <%=u[:col_1]==1? "checked":""%> data-toggle="toggle"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" <%=u[:col_2]==1? "checked":""%> data-toggle="toggle"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" <%=u[:col_3]==1? "checked":""%> data-toggle="toggle"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" <%=u[:col_4]==1? "checked":""%> data-toggle="toggle"></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

**Button which triggers the display of partial**

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add_access"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add User Permissions </button>
   <div id="input_user" style="display:none">
  <%= form_tag({controller: "request", action: "getuser_by_id"}, method: "POST", multipart: true, id: "search_users_form", "data-turbolinks": false, remote: true) %>
    <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" >   
    <button type= "submit"> Submit </button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, in the bootstrap toggle script you find this line of code

```
$(function() { $('input[type=checkbox][data-toggle^=toggle]').bootstrapToggle() })
```

So I added this code seperately to load the bootstrap-toggle checkbox in the partial.